# Rendering transparent windows

Tags: windows, winapi, directx, directx-9

The only method I know for rendering transparent windows is call to UpdateLayeredWindows which is terribly slow in case when I need to render result of D3D9 Render target.
I have to read render target data into system memory by calling GetRenderTargetData and 
then i have to render it on the screen by calling UpdateLayeredWindow.

Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee890072(v=vs.85).aspx 
there is a description of how to optimized rendering via "D3D9Ex Flip Mode Present to DWM".

Is there some kind of similar optimization for rendering top level transparent windows ?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't need per-pixel alpha, try using SetLayeredWindowAttributes (specifying either alpha or color key) instead and then paint/update as normal. I don't know how this will fare perf-wise compared to UpdateLayeredWindow, but worth a try perhaps.

Comment: I think I need per-pixel alpha. I hore there should be something similar to WDM optimization

Comment: [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17727/Unmanaged-Vista-Power) seems to do what you want.  I haven't tried it though.

Comment: this is exactly correct solution. Thanks much.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the answer in the comments:

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17727/Unmanaged-Vista-Power) seems to do what you want. 
Thanks for user [arx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292432/arx)